# Looking for a "bot" that evenly writes text at cursor position

Tags: phpstorm, bots

For recording a tutorial Iam looking for a tool that I can configure to evenly (x signs/second) write text/code at current cursor position. I just want the code writing video to be smooth and without any mistakes/corrections beeing done.

So basicaly I would write the text to some configuration file and have the tool re-write it later at the cursor position using some shortcut, while capturing it to a video.

Anyone knows a tool that can do that, preferably usable while in phpStorm?

Comment: Are you on Windows, Mac, or Linux? Writing a program to read a file, then put the characters into some function (e.g. `fputc()` to write it out, or whatever your language equivalent is) one-after-the-other is trivial to do cross-platform, but interacting with the GUI programs of your system is going to be system dependent. For example, it sounds like you'd want `AutoHotKey` for Windows, but maybe a shell script combined with `xdotool` for Linux. Not sure about MacOSX.

Comment: Iam on Windows 10. AutoHotKey looks promissing.